# How to change chart background color in Python-pptx

Tags: python, charts, python-pptx

I am using python-pptx to generate charts and I want to change the background of a chart, like the following so that the bg color is gray. However, the code fails as the plot "object has no attribute 'format'".

```
chart_fill = chart.plots[0].format.fill
chart_fill.solid()
chart_fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(191,191,191)
```

Here is what I want it to look like: 
[A chart with gray background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9oY6.png)

What is the python-pptx way to do this?

Comment: Check this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021200/change-chart-background-color-with-python-pptx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021200/change-chart-background-color-with-python-pptx)