# Change Chart Background Color with python-pptx

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am trying to change the background color of an existing Powerpoint chart with python-pptx. However, the 'fill' attribute doesn't seem to be implemented for charts yet. What I've tried so far:

```
chart_frame = shapes.add_chart(chart_type, left, top, width, height, chart_data)
chart = chart_frame.chart
chart.fill.solid()
chart.fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(r, g, b)
```

I've also tried to edit the fill attribute of the chart_frame and the plot, but it doesn't work.

Is there any workaround function to manipulate the underlying xml in order to solve this problem?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on my own in the meantime:

```
from pptx.oxml.xmlchemy import OxmlElement

chart_frame = shapes.add_chart(chart_type, left, top, width, height, chart_data)
chart = chart_frame.chart

shape_properties = OxmlElement("c:spPr")
chart.element.append(shape_properties)
fill_properties = OxmlElement("a:solidFill")
shape_properties.append(fill_properties)
scheme_color = OxmlElement("a:schemeClr")
color_value = dict(val="bg2")
scheme_color.attrib.update(color_value)
fill_properties.append(scheme_color)
```

This changes the color to background color 2 (bg2). In order to change it to a RGBColor, exchange the CT_SchemaColor object with a CT_sRGBColor object and update it accordingly with a hex color code:

```
rgb_color = OxmlElement("a:srgbClr")
color_value = dict(val='%02x%02x%02x' % (130, 130, 130))
rgb_color.attrib.update(color_value)
fill_properties.append(rgb_color)
```

Comment: How can I get the background to be clear?

Comment: Also, what about changing the border line color and other properties?